# How do you load service, resolve a function and pass data to controller through ocLazyLoad state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

In a `$stateProvider` state I want to:

- Load a service JS file
- Resolve a service function (API call)
- Pass resulting data to controller

**controllers/my-controller.js**

```
angular.module('app').
    controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope, serviceData){
        console.log(serviceData)
}]);
```

**config.js**

```
...

.state('main', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: 'templates/my-template.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    resolve: {
        dependencies: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                'controllers/my-controller.js'
            ])
        }],
        serviceData: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$injector', function($ocLazyLoad, $injector) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('services/my-service.js')
                .then(function(){
                    var $myService = $injector.get('MyService');
                    return $myService.GetData();
                })
        }]
    }
})
```

I would expect the controller to `console.log` the data coming back from the API call that MyService does (not included for brevity, but that part works). Instead, I get `undefined`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!